# windows python copy directories with same permission

Tags: python, windows, powershell, user-permissions

I need to copy entire directory tree structure from C:\ITsoftwares   to   \naso1\folder\ITsoftwares   with same directory and file permissions.

which will be better, Python script or powershell script.

i have seen powershell script, but Set-Acl command gives unauthorized error.

let me know some python code , so that i can copy the entire directory and file structure with same permissions.

can python  shutil.copy2  work here ?

Thank you for reading my post and answers. 
Vijay

Comment: Python's standard library, including `shutil`, doesn't have any way to copy ACLs -- not without using ctypes to call Windows APIs directly. You can use [robocopy.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145) for this task.

Comment: with robocopy, it adds  my name in the user permission and security, which i do not want.

Comment: Did you use the `/copyall` option? For example, `robocopy /e /copyall C:\ITsoftwares \naso1\folder\ITsoftwares`.

Comment: yes , this /e /copyall  is working , but robocopy does not copies folder by folder .  I have started the copy, i will update you once it completes.

Comment: Till now what i have seen. robocopy copies  all contents of   sub folders  in C:\ITsoftwares   to   \naso1\folder\ITsoftwares    . not folder by folder . just all contents of sub folders  into    \naso1\folder\ITsoftwares  .

Comment: i am sorry, i think , robocopy is copying folder by folder, if i have problem , then i will post again on this thread. now i have started that  robocopy script, its running.  Many thanks  Oryksun ,  and other who viewed my post.

Comment: Request other forum members to give ideas , if they have .please provide your feedback and ideas.